# Paypal "create" adaptive payments being instantly charged

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to set up a payment system with paypal for a site where the charging should not happen at payment confirmation time. I understand this is what the "CREATE" action type is for, you make the payment and then you use the execute payment to actually charge the account. Unfortunately, from what I'm seeing in the sandbox, the buyer gets charged immediately, and the execute payment returns a "paykey already used for a payment" error. The IPN notification similarly tells me the payment has already happened.

I'm currently using adaptive payments with 2 receivers. I'm sending the request from Java, using the code pasted below to get the paykey. Then I redirect the user to paypal and the payment is done (and charged).

Am I missing something?

```
List<PaymentReceiver> receiverList = setReceiversSingleProject(order);

    Element root = new Element("PayRequest");
    root.addNamespaceDeclaration("ns2", "http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap");

    // requestEnvelope and errorLanguage
    Element requestEnvelopeElement = new Element("requestEnvelope");
    Element errorLanguageElement = new Element("errorLanguage");
    errorLanguageElement.appendChild(errorLanguage);
    requestEnvelopeElement.appendChild(errorLanguageElement);
    root.appendChild(requestEnvelopeElement);

    // cancelUrl
    Element cancelUrlElement = new Element("cancelUrl");
    cancelUrlElement.appendChild(themeDisplay.getPortalURL()+"/basket");
    root.appendChild(cancelUrlElement);

    // actionType
    Element actionTypeElement = new Element("actionType");
    actionTypeElement.appendChild("CREATE");
    root.appendChild(actionTypeElement);

    // currencyCode
    Element currencyCodeElement = new Element("currencyCode");
    String projectCurrency = order.getMainProject().getCurrency();
    Currency currency = CurrencyLocalServiceUtil.getCurrency(projectCurrency);
    currencyCodeElement.appendChild(currency.getPaypalCode());
    root.appendChild(currencyCodeElement);

    // receiverList
    Element receiverListElement = new Element("receiverList");
    for (PaymentReceiver receiver : receiverList) {
        Element receiverElement = new Element("receiver");
        Element amountElement = new Element("amount");
        amountElement.appendChild(String.valueOf(receiver.getAmount()));
        Element emailElement = new Element("email");
        emailElement.appendChild(receiver.getEmail());
        Element primaryElement = new Element("primary");
        primaryElement.appendChild(receiver.isPrimary()?"true":"false");

        receiverElement.appendChild(amountElement);
        receiverElement.appendChild(emailElement);
        receiverElement.appendChild(primaryElement);
        receiverListElement.appendChild(receiverElement);
    }
    root.appendChild(receiverListElement);

    // returnUrl
    Element returnUrlElement = new Element("returnUrl");
    returnUrlElement.appendChild(returnURL);
    root.appendChild(returnUrlElement);

    // notifyUrl
    Element notifyUrlElement = new Element("ipnNotificationUrl");
    notifyUrlElement.appendChild(notifyURL);
    root.appendChild(notifyUrlElement);

    // Create document object
    Document doc = new Document(root);
    String result = doc.toXML();
    return result;
```